# How to match anything up to a sequence of characters in a group

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string sequence

```
game (
    name "!Mario (2000-11-19)(Dokokalaki)(JP)[h][Super Mario Bros.]"
    description "!Mario (2000-11-19)(Dokokalaki)(JP)[h][Super Mario Bros.]"
    rom ( name "!Mario (2000-11-19)(Dokokalaki)(JP)[h][Super Mario Bros.].nes" size 40976 crc 2e2bf112 md5 b1a0e41cfd30c1d61de3b7900232de59 sha1 7849ccb4cba5714042694da0e076092565023fc9 )
)

game (
    name "'89 Dennou Kyuusei Uranai (1988-12-10)(Induction Produce)(JP)"
    description "'89 Dennou Kyuusei Uranai (1988-12-10)(Induction Produce)(JP)"
    rom ( name "'89 Dennou Kyuusei Uranai (1988-12-10)(Induction Produce)(JP).nes" size 262160 crc 679db8f7 md5 31c66f47bd73568b4a675c9f8d995684 sha1 3918c52a5491695ed6b10b65f59622687dd7dc66 )
)
```

I want to match the characters between `rom ( name"` and `" size` if it matches a given crc value. I currently have this regex

`(?<=name ")(.+)(?= crc 2e2bf112)`

And that matches `!Mario (2000-11-19)(Dokokalaki)(JP)[h][Super Mario Bros.].nes" size 40976`.

I need instead a regex to match only  `!Mario (2000-11-19)(Dokokalaki)(JP)[h][Super Mario Bros.].nes`.

I've tried adding another lookaround like so
`(?<=name ")(.+)(?=" size)(?= crc 2e2bf112)`
but that doesn't match anything at all. I don't know the the length or value of the stuff after `size` except for the `crc`, so I can't match that with `[0-9]`s

I'm using RegExr to build my regular expressions, the regexes themselves will be used in .NET/C# code.

Comment: `(?=" size)(?= crc 2e2bf112)` doesn't do what you expect. It's an impossible match. Good for food.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
(?<=rom \( name "").*?(?="" size \d+ crc 2e2bf112)
```

**In C#:**

```
string theMatch = Regex.Match(yourString, @"(?<=rom \( name "").*?(?="" size \d+ crc 2e2bf112)").Value;
```

**Explanation**

- The lookbehind `(?<=rom \( name "")` serves as delimiter on the left
- `.*?` lazily matches chars up to...
- the point where the lookahead `(?="" size \d+ crc 2e2bf112)` can find the delimiter on the right

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: why there is two double quotes in your lookahead and lookbehind?

Comment: @AvinashRaj To escape the `"`

Comment: @AvinashRaj In verbatim strings, yes.

Comment: @AvinashRaj That's your opinion. I would be busy all day if I had to comment on what "is better". :) For a consistently formed string the space character is perfectly adequate, while `\s` matches vertical space and so on.

Comment: @AvinashRaj If Ron wants `\s`, he can decide and substitute it where the `[ ]` are used. He seems competent with regex, and his original expression used space characters.

Comment: Yep, this works great. +1 for the explanation too, Regex isn't my strongest suit :P Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with lookarounds, they make the job more complicated and bring no offsetting benefit.  Let the regex consume as much of the string as it needs to, and use capturing groups to extract the parts you're really interested in.

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"rom \( name ""(?<name>[^""]+)"" size \d+ crc 2e2bf112\b");
Match m = r.Match(subjectString);
if (m.Success) {
    resultString = m.Groups["name"].Value;
}
```